# Android Bitmap crop oval shape

Tags: android, bitmap, crop, bitmapfactory

Suppose I have a portrait bitmap that I have taken with my front facing camera.
How may I crop the bitmap to the shape of the oval-shaped overlay after I have taken the picture? The oval shape is centered to the screen. The oval shape has fixed height and width

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<!-- camera viewfinder here which fits the whole screen-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/cameraLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <!--Custom buttons-->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/record_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <!--Capture button-->

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<!--the oval-shaped overlay-->
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="318dp"
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/oval" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: How did you solved it Kelok?

Answer (score 0):

You can base your solution on how to crop a circle from a bitmap:

```
    @Override
    public Bitmap crop(Bitmap source) {
        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

        Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            source.recycle();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
                BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        float r = size / 2f;
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

        squaredBitmap.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Now just change `canvas.drawCircle` to `canvas.drawOval` and give it appropriate values.